# What is the French translation of “induced subgraphs”?

Tags: traduction, anglais, terminologie, mathématiques

I'm a French student studying graph theory and I encountered a translation issue while helping a boy on the math.stackexchange site.

A [vertex-induced subgraph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Vertex-InducedSubgraph.html) (sometimes simply called an "induced subgraph") is a subset of the vertices of a graph G together with any edges whose endpoints are both in this subset.

I found [an interresting link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240011/induced-subgraphs) about the English definition, but still, I'm not able to translate it in French.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only translation I found is “[*sous-graphe induit*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sous-graphe)”, but I don't see anything linking on “vertex”. The only thing I see is that “vertex” means “*sommet*” when talking about graphs, which is a node.

Comment: You can say: “sous-graphe induit par les sommets”

Answer (score 4):

Graph theory was a part of my studies so I can inform you for sure that you are looking for ***graphe*** (or ***sous-graphe*** depending on which one you want) ***induit***.

The vertex is simply called ***un sommet***.

The link between two vertices is called ***un arc***.

Answer (score 3):

Odds are most people will be unable to translate technical stuff. Even in the professional world people are encouraged to avoid using technical terms so the translation team doesn't get muddled up.

Here is what I suggest:

1. Find the item on wikipedia (English)
2. Click Français on the left side bar
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory#Subgraphs
   [https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexique_de_la_théorie_des_graphes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexique_de_la_th%C3%A9orie_des_graphes)
3. Search for the words you do know how to translate "sous-graphe" for example.

Best of luck with your French and maths.

Comment: "Even in the professional world people are encouraged to avoid using technical terms". Mathematicians would have a hard time to follow this advice. It may be simpler to redefine/recall the definition of technical terms.